# Increment variable name results in command not found

Tags: bash, variables, increment, variable-names

I am trying to increment a variable name based on the input and call the value after the loop is done.

```
for i in `seq 5`; do
  var$i="number is $i"
done
 echo $var2 $var5
```

Results in

```
./test.sh: line 4: var1=number is 1: command not found
./test.sh: line 4: var2=number is 2: command not found
./test.sh: line 4: var3=number is 3: command not found
./test.sh: line 4: var4=number is 4: command not found
./test.sh: line 4: var5=number is 5: command not found
```

There are 2 things I don't understand:

1. "var1=number is 1" is understood as a command.
2. var2 and var5 are actually generated but they are not displayed outside of the loop.

Comment: `var2` and `var5` aren't generated either. The syntax for variable assignment is `NAME=VALUE`. Parameter expansion comes later into play, and since `var$i` is not a valid variable name, you get a similar error as if you had written `var,i=value`. You could do an `eval var$i="number is $i"`, if you feel you **have** to create a variable like this, but in most cases, designing your script in a different way would be the better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the outcome required, the use of arrays are needed and so:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 5)
do
  var[$i]="number is $i"
done
for i in "${var[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Set the index and values for the array var accordingly and then loop through the array and print the values.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use variable names with a number in it like that: you really need to say:

```
var1=1
var2=2
var3=3
var4=4
var5=5
```

Another approach is the usage of arrays.

As far as increasing is concerned (this is not part of the question, but I give is anyways), you might use something like this:

```
Prompt> var1=1
Prompt> var2=$((var1+1))
Prompt> echo $var2
2
```

(Mind the double brackets for making calculations)

Answer (score 0):

1. "var1=number is 1" command not found because that's not a command. For example, you can write:

```sh
for i in `seq 5`; do
  echo var$i="number is $i"
done
```

And the output would look like

```
var1=number is 1
var2=number is 2
var3=number is 3
var4=number is 4
var5=number is 5
```

2. The variables have not been generated, you can't just dynamically generate variables. Try to use arrays